# Secure my connection string when sent from localhost over the network to my hosting site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

When we develop locally at time we need to connect to our live site from our localhost.

I've added encrypt=true to the connection string but I"m not sure if this encrypts the password and username sent to connect to the database.

So I downloaded TCPView to see if the connection is secure but could not tell?

How can I secure my password and username when sending over network and can I monitor it to make sure it is NOT being sent as plaintext?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that the ASP.NET application running on your localhost connects to the SQL Server on your live site using SQL authentication? If that's the case, the SQL authentication username and password are not sent in cleartext. When you use `encrypt=true` the client (localhost, in this case) connects to the server over SSL so that everything sent to and from the server is encrypted. If you don't use it, the authentication information is still encrypted using a self-signed SSL certificate but your queries and resultsets are not encrypted. That's according to this ServerFault Q/A anyway:

https://serverfault.com/questions/230403/does-the-password-get-sent-in-the-clear-when-connecting-to-sql-server